# pthreads, how do I know that another thread inside the process is not waiting?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

OS is Linux, working with pthreads

I have two worker threads that run forever, until a stop variable takes value true, and the threads terminate gracefully. Instead of doing busy waiting both threads call pthread_cond_wait  until a signal notifies for a new task. The system works well.

It is requested to create an "info" thread that will print some debugging information. The info thread will try to read and print information every 30 seconds.Part of this info, I would like to be the STATE of each worker thread. Is it possible to find if a thread is blocked in "pthread_cond_wait"? If the thread waits is pthread_cond_wait then STATE==waiting else the STATE==running.

```
 while ( (sharedvaluffer == 0) && (doneflag == 0) ) {
            pthread_cond_wait (&taks_added, &buffer);
        }
```

Of course we can do that we more code. We can add to the above snippet a global variable that 
marks that thread as locked. The code can be done

```
while ( (sharedvaluffer == 0) && (doneflag == 0) ) {
                lock;
                i_am_waiting = truel
                unlock
                pthread_cond_wait (&taks_added, &buffer);
 }
```

The question is, if there is an easier more scalable way. The stack of a waiting thread is

```
Thread 6 (Thread 0x40800940 (LWP 20732)):
#0  0x00002ba4567a9326 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
#1  0x00000000007ce2ed in worker(void*) ()
#2  0x00002ba4567a5193 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00002ba458a82f0d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the return of `pthread_self()` as identifier for the mutex ownership. Store and compare. Since a mutex can be acquired by a single thread at once, you will know which thread is running (not waiting), and which are not.

Comment: that does not work if the worker are locking the some mutex (ie in a shared mutex case)

Comment: Why not? Each thread has its own id. Keep an accessible `pthread_t current_owner` and update it every time a worker thread acquires the mutex. Your info thread then compares this variable to the id of each worker thread. Keep in mind pthread_t is an `int` on Linux, but generally a structure in other systems, thus you can't rely on atomicity, requiring an extra lock.

Answer (score 1):

You could register a shared structure **s** in the mutex with [pthread_mutexattr_getpshared](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutexattr_getpshared.html), where each thread registers its state (running, not running) with the aid of `pthread_self()`.

Before checking the condition variable, you can set `s[pthread_self()]->state = WAITING`, and after the check you can set `s[pthread_self()]->state = WORKING`.

Be sure to design the structure such as no race condition will occur.

Answer (score 1):

I would go the simple route and just include a state enum per thread. Prior to each conceptual state change you would alter the state.

```
void worker(void* parm)
{
    threadstate_t *state = (threadstate_t*)parm;

    /* ... */
    while (...) {
         state->current = STATE_WORKING;

         /* ... */

         state->current = STATE_WAITING;
         /* res = pthread_cond_wait(cond, mutex); */
    }
}
```

Then in your interrogration thread:

```
void worker_dbg(void* parm)
{
    threadstate_t *states = (threadstate_t*)parm;
    int i;

    while (run) {
        for (i = 0; i < NWORKERS; ++i) {
            /* _state is a map of states to strings */
            printf("Thread %d: %s\n", states[i].id, _state[states[i].current]);
        }
        sleep(30);
    }
}
```

If you're *off* by 30 seconds because the state got updated *right* after you printed, it doesn't really matter. No need to lock on the state as you only write from the owning worker and you only read from the debug thread.

Comment: the main principle is similar to mine, but you attach the state to threads, while I do it on mutexes, so your approach is cleaner than mine. +1

Comment: You could take your approach and roll it into mine by just adding each mutex to the state enum. As granular as you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are using a mutex which is locked when the condition is notified, if so, in your information thread, simply try locking that mutex - if you acquire it, well it's possible that at the time you sampled, the thread is waiting, else if it would block, then you know the thread is doing it's thing (i.e. it has acquired that mutex which means it's in it's critical section)

Comment: the answer of Nim is good. On the contrary. Using trylock for the mutex means that upon success the other thread is sleeping. The problem with the solution is that the mutex_ might be shared by both worker threads

Comment: @akappa, why? it's a a trylock attempt, if it fails, fine, the thread is busy, if it succeeds, you release it immediately but you know the thread was a sleep at that point in time. What is the downside? in the latter case you have an extra lock/unlock on the mutex which the other thread is forced to wait for - unless this is some real-time critical application, I don't see that as being a problem!?!

Comment: you said it: "unless this is some real-time critical application" :)